# Helpers en Vuex y Nuxtjs

Tags: vue.js, vuex

estoy utilizando Nuxtjs y Vuex, mi pregunta es como puedo utilizar el state, mutations,actions,getters etc, si he modularizado el store en archivos separados, utilizando los helpers de vuex. Acontinuación muestro como lo estoy intentando utilizar, no me arroja ningun error en consola, pero tampoco me renderiza en la vista

```
<h1>Username: {{currentUser}}</h1>

<script>
import {mapState} from 'vuex'
export default {
  name: "index",
  computed: {
    ...mapState({
      currentUser : 'authentication/authenticated'
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Buen dia amigo si tienes tu state en un archivo llamado authentication.js tienes que acceder a el usando authentication como un objeto, de esta manera podras llegar al objeto authenticated:

```js
...mapState({
      authenticated: (state) => state.authentication.authenticated,
    }),
```

de esta manera guardaras en el objeto authenticated el valor del state (recuerda siempre acceder al state mediante la notacion de objeto)